# Why my components don't display on my React page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I'm learning React and building an app with multiple pages, I made a Routes file which looks like this:

```
import 'swiper/swiper.min.css';
import React from "react";

import { Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";

import Home from "../pages/Home";
import Catalog from "../pages/Catalog";
import Detail from "../pages/Detail";

const Router = () => {
    return (
        <Routes>
            <Route
                path='/:category/search/:keyword'
                component={Catalog}
            />
            <Route
                path='/:category/:id'
                component={Detail}
            />
            <Route
                path='/:category'
                component={Catalog}
            />
            <Route
                path='/'
                exact
                component={Home}
            />
        </Routes>
    );
}
```

And App.js looks like this:

```
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';

import Header from './components/header/Header';
import Footer from './components/footer/Footer';

import Router from './config/Router';

function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
    <Routes>
    <Route render={props =>{
          <>
              <Header {...props}/>
              <Router/>
              <Footer/>
          </>
      }}/>
    </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

As you see, I have a browser router and Route which passes props to a component(as I understood) but for some reason the components don't display on the page(original components just have  with their name inside of them, but they don't display in App.js).

And my console also says:

```
No routes matched location "/"
```

In routes.jsx file. I'm guessing it should lead to main page, but for some reason the route doesn't match and components in App.js don't display.

Comment: @Quentin, hi! i used Router just below Header component, as you can see in the code(it was like that in the tutorial)

Comment: @Carl Which version of `react-router-dom` do you using?

Comment: @MajidM. hi! my version of react-router-dom is 6.0.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've said you're using **react-router-dom** 6.0.2, and it seems that the tutorial you are following is for the older version (5?). There were some breaking changes in version 6.

You need to change your `Router` component to use `element` instead of `component`:

```
const Router = () => {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/:category/search/:keyword" element={<Catalog />} />
      <Route path="/:category/:id" element={<Detail />} />
      <Route path="/:category" element={<Catalog />} />
      <Route path="/" exact element={<Home />} />
    </Routes>
  );
};
```

and also your `App` component seems to be getting in the way with the nested route.

I think it can be simplified to:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <>
        <Header />
        <Router />
        <Footer />
      </>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

You can see a [working demo on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-ghjz82?file=src/App.jsx)

Comment: thank you, it actually worked! but could i ask why you removed <Route render=props...?

Comment: You don't really need it v6. Here's a [link](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/main/docs/upgrading/v5.md#advantages-of-route-element) with more info, but in your case in particular that nested route seemed to cause problems.

Answer (score 3):

In [Version 6.0.0](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/overview) there is not any `component` prop in `Route`. It has been changed to `element`. So you need to change your `Router` to :

```
 const Router = () => {
    return (
        <Routes>
            <Route
                path='/:category/search/:keyword'
                element={Catalog}
            />
            <Route
                path='/:category/:id'
                element={Detail}
            />
            <Route
                path='/:category'
                element={Catalog}
            />
            <Route
                path='/'
                exact
                element={Home}
            />
        </Routes>
    );
}
```

[image: Edit agitated-firefly-27qu6]

Comment: i actually did it but components still don't display for some reason and No routes matched location "/" error is still present

Comment: @Carl Another problem in your code is the `App` component. You don't need to use `Routes` and `Route` when you have defined them on  `Router` component.

Comment: thank you, i'll look it up. i just don't know much about router in react, but thanks for your answer xd